# Django Query using Foreign Key

Tags: python, django

I'm starting to work with queries in django and I'm trying to replicate the results of a join in sql.

I have a two models that represent a parent (WaiverAdult) and a child (WaiverMinor). I would like to return the parent and child in the query set, so I can group them in a formatted template, like so:

```
  John Dad
    Tommy Son
    Amber Daughter

  Jen Jones
    Stevie Jones
    Mike Jones
```

**MODELS:**

```
class WaiverAdult(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)

class WaiverMinor(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    parent = models.ForeignKey(WaiverAdult, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**VIEW:**

```
class WaiverListView(ListView):

    waiver_adults = WaiverAdult.objects.all().prefetch_related(
        'waiverminor_set').order_by('created')

    queryset = [adult.waiverminor_set.all() for adult in waiver_adults]

    context_object_name = "waiver_list"
    template_name = 'waiver/waiver_list.html'
```

**Template Sample to outline what I'm attempting:**

```
                    {% for adult in waiver_list %}

                    <tr>
                        <td>{{adult.last_name}}, {{adult.first_name}}</td>
                    </tr>

                        {% for child in waiver_list %}
                            <tr>
                                <td>{{child.last_name}}, {{child.first_name}}</td>
                            </tr>
                        {% endfor %}


                    {% endfor %}
```

What is the proper way to write this query?  Thank you in advance.  I truly appreciate the guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish to access related objects, the best way is to prefetch them so you are not hitting the database again every time you want to access a related object. You can do this like so:

```
waiver_adults = WaiverAdult.objects.all().prefetch_related('waiverminor_set').order_by('created')
```

This will be the queryset for your view so you can write in the view:

```
queryset = waiver_adults
```

Then in the template you can loop through in the way you want by doing:

```
{% for adult in waiver_list %}

<tr>
    <td>{{adult.last_name}}, {{adult.first_name}}</td>
</tr>

  {% for child in adult.waiverminor_set.all %}
       <tr>
         <td>{{child.last_name}}, {{child.first_name}}</td>
       </tr>
  {% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I’ll need to research the impact of prefetching when the app requires retrieving/displaying data that can be updated at a high frequency.  How would that be written without prefetching?

Comment: You can do the same thing without the prefetch statement: `WaiverAdult.objects.all().order_by('created')`. That will still allow you to do  `waiverminor_set.all()` on each element in that queryset. But for each `WaiverAdult` you do that it will make another database call. So if you have many `WaiverAdult` records and each has several `WaiverMinor` related records then you are making a huge number of database calls which will almost surely be slower than prefetching which will do the same thing in one call. It's typically better to prefetch data you need instead of making subsequent calls.

Comment: Thank you.  This makes sense, but I'm uncertain of how this is then references within the template.  I set my context variable to waiver_list and then in the template I assume I can loop over it and display the waiveradult and then each waiverminor beneath?  I'm failing at all attempts.  I updated the code above to reflect how it's setup now.

Comment: I believe I misled you with my list comprehension since I didn't know what you were trying to do. I've updated my answer as per your edit.

Comment: Yes.  Thank you.  I just did some more research before coming back to this and realized that I needed queryset = waiver_adults.  Thank you very much for returning back and providing the additional response.